# angular2 call http.get request to open file

Tags: angular

I'm trying to do a http.get request to fetch a file from a local directory, at the moment I just want to console.log the response that the api get is being requested. The `getFile()` shows the console.log but calling the `http`, not sure how `http` is used in angular2; I know in angular1 it use `.then` for a response.

```javascript
import { Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';

getFile() {
  this.http.get('//localhost:1337/getFile');
  console.log('get me the file');
}
```

Api endpoint:

```javascript
app.get('/getFile', function(req, res) {
  var contents = fs.readFileSync('journey.xml');
  console.log('Reading File....' + contents);   
  res.send(contents);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you need to change the request type of File to blob, assuming you're not simply fetching a plaintext file. something like

```
this.http.get(url,{responseType: 'blob'}).subscribe(...)
```

Otherwise, you will get an error as angular attempts to parse the response as json. There are other types, which you can read [here](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest#responseType).

**For your case, I believe the responseType would be 'text'**

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to observable returned by http service:

```javascript
import { Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

getFile() {
  this.http.get('//localhost:1337/getFile')
    .map(response => response.text())
    .subscribe(data => console.log('get me the file', data))
}
```

Comment: I'm getting  "Uncaught Response with status: 0  for URL: null" error and GET http://url/getFile empty response

Comment: If you open //localhost:1337/getFile in new tab what does it show you?

Comment: ah sorry my api server wasn't running. I'm getting the data back in my console.log, but how can I actually open/download the file when I call getFile()? If I open /getFile in another tab it downsloads the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use subscribe

```
.subscribe(
    res => this.somename= res.json(),
    error =>  console.log(error));
```

OR

```
.subscribe(
  function(response) { console.log("Success Response" + response)},
  function(error) { console.log("Error happened" + error)},
  function() { console.log("the subscription is completed")}
 );
```

Comment: can you explain your answer? where did the this._OBJ_ came from?

Comment: this._OBJ_ is just an example, you just define some name and assign to res.json();

Answer (score 0):

http.get method returns an Observable of HTTP Responses
You might wanna try something like this:

```
this.http.get('//localhost:1337/getFile').subscribe(f => {
        console.log(f)
    }, (error) => {
        //handle error
    }, () => {
        //complete
    });
```